# Unique experiences of southwest Europe

Tags: europe, planning

I'm an American, going to southwest Europe soon. I'm looking for unique things to do. By unique I mean things where I could not get a similar experience at home or even other places in America.

For example someone sent me [a newspaper article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/lifestyle/travel/in-venice-learning-to-row-your-own-boat/2014/04/17/a89c62d8-bf53-11e3-bcec-b71ee10e9bc3_story.html) that in Venice you can get lessons on rowing a gondola. That seems like a very uniquely Venice thing to do. On the other hand there are lots of great parks and trails with natural views in Europe but America has great national parks too. The views aren't exactly the same but it's still similar, not as much a unique thing.

I guess you probably want me to tell you the specific place I am asking about but I don't have just one. I wanted to find some interesting things to do and then plan my path around that. But to hopefully narrow it down some, the rough plan goes northeast Spain, south coast of France, north Italy, Switzerland, and Bavaria. Would it help if I asked separately for different regions or cities?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Our format isn't well-suited to questions like yours; I would suggest you start with a discussion forum and a bit of research on your own— there are numerous guide books and websites where you can get firsthand and expert opinions. We can then help you flesh out the details. For a better understanding of how our site works, I encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help].

Comment: Ahh dang. I saw some more recommendation-y questions here than other SE sites and thought maybe this would fly. Guidebooks have been unhelpful to me this time around. Lots of good info but not on unique stuff. Or if it's in there it's really hard to find. Have any advice on how to do this specific kind of research? I already spent many hours trying but not succeeding. If not I guess I'll go looking for a good forum or two... thanks.

Comment: Recommendations need a *lot* of context, as "unique" can't be objectively determined. An enthusiast's eye always discerns greater detail than a generalist, for instance. Thus, one person might get excited about a particular depiction found in a particular church, whereas his traveling companion might say "meh, all churches are the same," and no amount of argument would ever convince them otherwise. So any request for suggestions becomes an infinite list with no right answer.

Comment: 'south coast of France' needs to be precised wether you mean 'Mediterranean coast' or 'Atlantic coast' .

Comment: @audionuma: "south coast of France" unambiguously refers to the Mediterranean coast.The Atlantic coast is the west coast.

Comment: @tonyk : Well, maybe for you, not for most french native speakers. There's no such thing as 'south coast' in French, we do have 'south west' and 'south east'. Nevertheless, given other clues in the OP message, the meaning was (sort of) unambiguous. Sorry for trying to improve the OP's message.

Comment: @audionuma: What I said is true in English. What you said may well be true in French.

Comment: After this was closed I asked other places and I got similar confused, to put it politely, responses about my use of directions. I did mean Mediterranean coast. Was only looking at a map and did not know about local usage. Happy I learned at least something from this question!